# Show the Value on form real time - app script

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, google-apps-script

i need help on the web app form. im faceing issue how to show the value real time on webapp form. i right code.gs but im unbale to create javascript for run the function interval level.

please help me on this.

```js
function getTime(){
    
  const ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
      const wsData = ss.getSheetByName("Run")
      const emp = [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()];
      const now = new Date();
      const d= wsData.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().reverse();
      const emp_i = d.findIndex(r => r[1] === emp.toString());
      if (emp_i == -1 && d[emp_i][4] == "");
      const hour = new Date(now - new Date(d[emp_i][3])).toISOString().substr(11,8 );
      return hour;
}

var Duration = [getTime()];
```

```html
<label for="Duration">Last Activity Duration</label>
            <select class="w3-select"  id="Duration">
               
                <? for(let i=0;i<Duration.length;i++){ ?>
                <option>
                    <?= Duration[i]; ?>
                </option>
                <? }?>
            </select>
        </div>
```

Comment: I am not sure I completely understand what is your end goal here - so you'd like to run the `getTime` function in the client-side of the web app? And it should the real time while on the app?

Comment: Yes are you correct..can you help me on this

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how your getTime() is going to return an array:

```
function getTime() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  const wsData = ss.getSheetByName("Run")
  const emp = [Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()];
  const now = new Date();
  const d = wsData.getDataRange().getDisplayValues().reverse();
  const emp_i = d.findIndex(r => r[1] === emp.toString());//emp.toString() doesn't look right
  if (emp_i == -1 && d[emp_i][4] == "");//I don't think this line is doing anything
  const hour = new Date(now - new Date(d[emp_i][3])).toISOString().substr(11, 8);
  return hour;
}
```

but I think you need a doGet() something like this:

```
function doGet(e) {
  const ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  let t = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('filename');//create a template
  t.Duration = getTime(); // assign global variables to the template this way
  return t.evaluate();//this is htmloutput
}
```

It's actually hard to tell what you want from your code.  It might be better to just explain what you want to do in words.

Comment: Hi thank you .....In this code I'm taking the hours value.. for ex. In the gsheet already have time stamp as start time and Im calculating current time - staart time =  hours.. I hope you got my point

Comment: The emp I is checking the current user any activity is not completed and then show the hours how match the stay on the one activity. I hop I explain to you ...just I need the if I have right something in code.gs how I can set interval function And show the output on html

Comment: I don't understand the last comment.  Perhaps you can rewrite it using complete sentences.

Comment: Hi , the above code gettime function is correct , I need help on  how  I will set interval function and then  show the value on html.

Comment: Well that's  something that we disagree on, but here's a [reference for setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval) but you also could use templated html or window.onload

Answer (score 0):

If you want to retrieve the date in real time, you will have to handle everything in the client side and use the server side to make the request, something similar to this:

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet(e) {
   return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('html');
}
```

**html.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <base target="_top">
   </head>
   <p id="time"></p>
   <body>
      <script>
         var timeDisplay = document.getElementById("time");
         function getTime() {
            var dateString = new Date().toLocaleString("ZONE", {timeZone: "YOUR_TIMEZONE"});
            var formattedString = dateString.replace(", ", " - ");
            timeDisplay.innerHTML = formattedString;
         }
         setInterval(getTime, 1000);
      </script>
   </body>
</html>
```

However, if you'd like to simply call the function from the Apps Script code, you should update your client side code to this:

```
<script>
   for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
      google.script.run.getTime();
   }
</script>
```

Communicating with the Apps Script functions is done by using `google.script.run`. This is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that allows HTML-service pages to call the server-side functions.

#### Reference

- [Apps Script Web Apps](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web);
- [Communicate With Server Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).